Maven is not picking up environment variables from `.env` file when trying to compile Quarkus project
I am using a M1 MAC and GRAALVM 23 using ./mvnw package -Dnative command. However I am running into issues where it's not picking up the environment variables from my .env file. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this? My whole intention is to compile this and then run this in Docker using the Dockerfile.native file that is provided by Quarkus. It works just fine locally. I had to limit the output below since it was beyond the 30K character limit.
java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00014: The config property JWT_SECRET is required but it could not be found in any config source
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.convertValue(SmallRyeConfig.java:436)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducerUtil.getValue(ConfigProducerUtil.java:100)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducerUtil.getValue(ConfigProducerUtil.java:60)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer.produceStringConfigProperty(ConfigProducer.java:52)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_Subclass.produceStringConfigProperty$$superforward(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_Subclass$$function$$10.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ConfigStaticInitCheckInterceptor.aroundInvoke(ConfigStaticInitCheckInterceptor.java:47)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ConfigStaticInitCheckInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_Subclass.produceStringConfigProperty(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_ProducerMethod_produceStringConfigProperty_Slb1-DO4BbQxgDjjOw2BuNv12-I_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_ProducerMethod_produceStringConfigProperty_Slb1-DO4BbQxgDjjOw2BuNv12-I_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_ProducerMethod_produceStringConfigProperty_Slb1-DO4BbQxgDjjOw2BuNv12-I_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_ProducerMethod_produceStringConfigProperty_Slb1-DO4BbQxgDjjOw2BuNv12-I_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.CurrentInjectionPointProvider.get(CurrentInjectionPointProvider.java:48)
        at org.devtop.filters.AuthFilter_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
        at org.devtop.filters.AuthFilter_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.devtop.filters.AuthFilter_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:119)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:38)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:32)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCacheContextInstances.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCacheContextInstances.java:19)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
        at org.devtop.filters.AuthFilter_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.devtop.filters.AuthFilter_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:559)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:539)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:572)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl$3.get(ArcContainerImpl.java:331)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl$3.get(ArcContainerImpl.java:328)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.BeanContainerImpl$1.create(BeanContainerImpl.java:58)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.runtime.ArcBeanFactory.createInstance(ArcBeanFactory.java:27)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.startup.RuntimeInterceptorDeployment.createInterceptorInstances(RuntimeInterceptorDeployment.java:159)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.startup.RuntimeInterceptorDeployment.<init>(RuntimeInterceptorDeployment.java:65)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.startup.RuntimeDeploymentManager.deploy(RuntimeDeploymentManager.java:98)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder.createDeployment(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:154)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyReactiveProcessor$setupDeployment713137389.deploy_1(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyReactiveProcessor$setupDeployment713137389.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1161)
        (internal stack frames of the image generator are omitted)


        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisFuture.ensureDone(AnalysisFuture.java:70)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisType.ensureOnTypeReachableTaskDone(AnalysisType.java:750)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisField.lambda$beforeFieldValueAccess$0(AnalysisField.java:538)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisType.forAllSuperTypes(AnalysisType.java:730)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisType.forAllSuperTypes(AnalysisType.java:713)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisType.forAllSuperTypes(AnalysisType.java:709)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisField.beforeFieldValueAccess(AnalysisField.java:537)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.ameta.FieldValueInterceptionSupport.computeAndCacheFieldValueInterceptor(FieldValueInterceptionSupport.java:154)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.ameta.FieldValueInterceptionSupport.lookupFieldValueInterceptor(FieldValueInterceptionSupport.java:143)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.ameta.FieldValueInterceptionSupport.hasFieldValueTransformer(FieldValueInterceptionSupport.java:247)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.ameta.CustomTypeFieldHandler.handleField(CustomTypeFieldHandler.java:61)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.analysis.NativeImagePointsToAnalysis.onFieldAccessed(NativeImagePointsToAnalysis.java:118)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.onFieldAccessed(AnalysisUniverse.java:667)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisField.registerAsAccessed(AnalysisField.java:267)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisField.registerAsUnsafeAccessed(AnalysisField.java:326)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.PointsToAnalysisField.registerAsUnsafeAccessed(PointsToAnalysisField.java:84)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.reflect.ReflectionDataBuilder.registerTypesForField(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:809)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.reflect.ReflectionDataBuilder.registerField(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:610)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.reflect.ReflectionDataBuilder.registerFields(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:556)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.reflect.ReflectionDataBuilder.lambda$register$34(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:516)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.reflect.ReflectionDataBuilder.lambda$runConditionalInAnalysisTask$2(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:184)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.executeCommand(CompletionExecutor.java:166)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$executeService$0(CompletionExecutor.java:152)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.compute(ForkJoinTask.java:1726)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.compute(ForkJoinTask.java:1717)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$InterruptibleTask.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1641)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:507)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1458)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:2034)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:189)
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Class initialization of io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl failed. Use the option 

    '--initialize-at-run-time=io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl'

 to explicitly request initialization of this class at run time. Exception thrown by the class initializer:

java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00014: The config property JWT_SECRET is required but it could not be found in any config source
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.convertValue(SmallRyeConfig.java:436)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducerUtil.getValue(ConfigProducerUtil.java:100)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducerUtil.getValue(ConfigProducerUtil.java:60)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer.produceStringConfigProperty(ConfigProducer.java:52)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_Subclass.produceStringConfigProperty$$superforward(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_Subclass$$function$$10.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ConfigStaticInitCheckInterceptor.aroundInvoke(ConfigStaticInitCheckInterceptor.java:47)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ConfigStaticInitCheckInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_Subclass.produceStringConfigProperty(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_ProducerMethod_produceStringConfigProperty_Slb1-DO4BbQxgDjjOw2BuNv12-I_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_ProducerMethod_produceStringConfigProperty_Slb1-DO4BbQxgDjjOw2BuNv12-I_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_ProducerMethod_produceStringConfigProperty_Slb1-DO4BbQxgDjjOw2BuNv12-I_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer_ProducerMethod_produceStringConfigProperty_Slb1-DO4BbQxgDjjOw2BuNv12-I_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.CurrentInjectionPointProvider.get(CurrentInjectionPointProvider.java:48)
        at org.devtop.filters.AuthFilter_Bean.doCreate(Unknown Source)
        at org.devtop.filters.AuthFilter_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.devtop.filters.AuthFilter_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:119)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:38)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:32)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCacheContextInstances.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCacheContextInstances.java:19)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
        at org.devtop.filters.AuthFilter_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.devtop.filters.AuthFilter_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:559)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:539)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:572)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl$3.get(ArcContainerImpl.java:331)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl$3.get(ArcContainerImpl.java:328)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.BeanContainerImpl$1.create(BeanContainerImpl.java:58)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.runtime.ArcBeanFactory.createInstance(ArcBeanFactory.java:27)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.startup.RuntimeInterceptorDeployment.createInterceptorInstances(RuntimeInterceptorDeployment.java:159)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.startup.RuntimeInterceptorDeployment.<init>(RuntimeInterceptorDeployment.java:65)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.startup.RuntimeDeploymentManager.deploy(RuntimeDeploymentManager.java:98)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder.createDeployment(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:154)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyReactiveProcessor$setupDeployment713137389.deploy_1(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyReactiveProcessor$setupDeployment713137389.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1161)
        (internal stack frames of the image generator are omitted)


        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:97)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationSupport.ensureClassInitialized(ClassInitializationSupport.java:229)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationSupport.computeInitKindAndMaybeInitializeClass(ClassInitializationSupport.java:428)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationSupport.computeInitKindAndMaybeInitializeClass(ClassInitializationSupport.java:366)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationSupport.maybeInitializeAtBuildTime(ClassInitializationSupport.java:178)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationSupport.maybeInitializeAtBuildTime(ClassInitializationSupport.java:167)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.SVMHost.onTypeReachable(SVMHost.java:350)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.onTypeReachable(AnalysisUniverse.java:676)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisType.lambda$new$0(AnalysisType.java:336)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisFuture.ensureDone(AnalysisFuture.java:69)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisType.ensureOnTypeReachableTaskDone(AnalysisType.java:750)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisType.onReachable(AnalysisType.java:629)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AtomicUtils.atomicSetAndRun(AtomicUtils.java:49)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisType.registerAsReachable(AnalysisType.java:591)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.reflect.ReflectionDataBuilder.registerClass(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:256)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.reflect.ReflectionDataBuilder.lambda$register$6(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:202)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.reflect.ReflectionDataBuilder.lambda$runConditionalInAnalysisTask$2(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:184)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.executeCommand(CompletionExecutor.java:166)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$executeService$0(CompletionExecutor.java:152)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.compute(ForkJoinTask.java:1726)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.compute(ForkJoinTask.java:1717)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$InterruptibleTask.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1641)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:507)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.externalHelpQuiesce(ForkJoinPool.java:2535)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.helpQuiescePool(ForkJoinPool.java:2569)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitQuiescence(ForkJoinPool.java:3808)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.complete(CompletionExecutor.java:208)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis.doTypeflow(PointsToAnalysis.java:613)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis.finish(PointsToAnalysis.java:601)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.AbstractAnalysisEngine.runAnalysis(AbstractAnalysisEngine.java:157)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:832)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:592)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:554)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:528)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:711)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.start(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:139)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1161)
...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        0.4s (4.9% of total time) in 44 GCs | Peak RSS: 0.82GB | CPU load: 3.59
========================================================================================================================
Failed generating 'vault-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner' after 8.1s.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14.745 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-02T10:30:38-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.15.1:build (default) on project vault-service: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep$ImageGenerationFailureException: Image generation failed. Exit code: 1
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.imageGenerationFailed(NativeImageBuildStep.java:489)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:278)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:733)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:856)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1575)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

pox.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.na</groupId>
    <artifactId>vault-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.13.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.15.1</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.3.1</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate ORM specific dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC driver dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                            <goal>native-image-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parameters>true</parameters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
                <quarkus.native.enabled>true</quarkus.native.enabled>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>

Application.properties
# configure your datasource
quarkus.datasource.db-kind = postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username = postgres
quarkus.datasource.password = password
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test

# drop and create the database at startup (use `update` to only update the schema)
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation = update


It looks like I'll have to refactor pom.xml file as I am using dependencies that are not supported for GraalVM compilation

Is there a reason you are not using quarkus-smallrye-jwt?

@geoand Yes I have 2 other micro services that is not using the JWT properties like issuer etc like quarkus-smallrye-jwt wants so I needed to use a library that was more flexible
